# Proper response when we pray, but outcomes are negative?

Tags: karma, prayer

What is the proper response/behavior of someone who prays with fervor, but for whom outcomes are negative?

For example:

Praying for someone else’s good health. Praying success in life events. Let’s say people pray in hopes of a better life in some way, yet the outcomes of such events can be failures.

In those occasions, my question is what do scriptures say about how one should react to failures and outcomes? Is there something that should be done, ie, pray more, focus on karma, or simply do nothing?

Comment: When you are engaged in some sort of sadhna what really matters is: 1. Intent 2. Patience 3. Sincere Efforts.

Comment: Listen, it is impossible to find out the results of prayer. There are too many factors to take into account.

Comment: negative outcomes, even after prayer?  Can you clarify as to what did you expect and what are the outcomes? @paneerlovr

Comment: Example, praying for someone else’s good health.  Praying success in life events.  Let’s say people pray in hopes of a better life in some way, yet the outcomes of such events can be failures.  In those occasions, my question is what do scriptures say about how one should react to failures and outcomes.  Is there something that should be done, ie, pray more, focus on karma, or simply do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sri Krishna says in BG

> कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन।
>
> मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि।।2.47।।
>
> Let your claim lie on action alone and never on the fruits; you should never be a cause for the fruits of action; let not your attachment be to inaction.

---

One's **prArabdha** (stored merit) will work most of the time, irrespective of one's sincere and steadfast efforts.

If efforts are being made for the benefit of others, the outcome will be according to the combined **prArabdha** (stored merit) of that particular segment of people.

Comment: But wouldn't Krishna grant wishes to his devotee if his devotee wish for something? If yes then what devotee should do if that wish didn't fullfilled by krishna even after doing devotion? This is the real question. If Krishna is not fullfilling wish then a devotee should do what to make him fullfill my(devotee's) desire.

Comment: @Rishabh: Sri Krishna, being a Yogi of the highest Order (I don't accept incarnation concept please , and hence I do not consider Sri Krishna to be  an incarnation of vishnu),  advocated the concept of getting benefits out of one's own efforts, but not on DIVINE grace alone.  उद्धरेदात्मनाऽऽत्मानं नात्मानमवसादयेत्। - One should save oneself by oneself; one should not lower oneself. (BG 6:5).  Further, after expounding Gita to Arjuna, finally he says यथेच्छसि तथा कुरु।।18.63।। - Pondering over this as a whole, do as you like. So the God will give results according to one's prArabdha and Karma.